# Update struct or nested field in bigquery

Tags: go, google-bigquery

Correct way to update a nested field or a struct in a BigQuery table.

SQL statement:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET Employee.name = 'some string'
WHERE id = 10
```

Here's my code:

```
ctx := context.Background()
client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("bigquery.NewClient: %v", err)
}
defer client.Close()

q := client.Query("UPDATE myTable SET Employee.name = 'some string' WHERE id = @id  ")
q.Parameters = []bigquery.QueryParameter{
  { 
   Name: "id",
    Value: 10
  },
}

job, err := q.Run(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

status, err := job.Wait(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if err := status.Err(); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

My table:
[image]

How do I update this struct or nested field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately BigQuery does not support updating separate fields of a query or a nested field. The following syntax is not supported:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET Employee.name = 'some string'
WHERE id = 10
```

We can update structs only as a whole:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET Employee = STRUCT('aaa', 'bbb')
WHERE id = 10
```

Comment: I see. How about if I want to update more than one  field? Like "SET Employee.name = 'some string', Employee..position = 'some string here'". Thanks btw!

Comment: It is similar. For a struct with two fields it will be: `UPDATE myTable SET Employee = STRUCT('name_here', 'position_here') WHERE id = 10`

Comment: Btw, is there a way where I can explicitly put specific struct field? Example: `STRUCT("name": "John", "position": "Manager")`

Comment: Try `UPDATE myTable SET Employee = STRUCT('John' as name, 'Manager' as position) WHERE id = 10`

Comment: I see. I will try this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MERGE statement is very powerful in BigQuery, you could do many operations with it, including UPDATE any fields of any rows.

try this below

```
merge into `myTable` as dest
using (
  SELECT 
    * EXCEPT(Employee),
    STRUCT(
      name = 'some string',
      salary = Employee.salary,
      position = Employee.position
    ) AS Employee
  FROM `myTable`
  WHERE id = @id 
) AS source
ON source.id = dest.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
      col_1 = source.col_1, col_2 = source.col_2 ...
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Do you mean to set SET dest.col_1=source.col_1 ?