# Update a struct column in bigquery using another table in bigquery having string columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table A with schema

```
ID -> type(String)
experience -> type(Array of Struct)
```

`A.experience` column has 6 subfield of type string.

I wish to update `A.experience` using another table B (which can be joined on basis of ID) and has 6 more columns which correspond to keys in A.experience.

All the columns in table B are of type String.

Here's what I tried

```
update  A
set A.experience = (company,starts_at,ends_at,eid,title,location) 
from B
where A.id = B.id;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update struct or nested field in bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66432739/update-struct-or-nested-field-in-bigquery)

Comment: @Jaytiger I can leverage your help; I can make additional 6 columns in table A, and then update A.experience =  STRUCT(A.1,A.2...A.6) ; later i'll drop these 6 columns. That's what i can think of right now

Comment: Any reason to create additional 6 columns to update A.experience ? I think you can directly update A.experience using B's columns.

Comment: @Jaytiger I am not able to assign values of B to a Struct column of A. So i thought of this workaround of creating extra temp columns. Then i can use STRUCT() to assign values. Seems like an overkill, but i can't find anything else. I can't even update single entries of struct, that's another problem.

Comment: @AlmightyHeathcliff It will be better if you can add some sample data or at least schema of both the tables in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I clearly understood your queston, but you seem to want to do this. let me know if I'm wrong.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE A AS
SELECT 'id1' id, 
       [STRUCT('C1'AS company, '2010-01-01 11:00:00' AS starts_at, '2010-01-01 12:00:00' AS ends_at, 'eid1' AS eid, 'title1' AS title, 'loc1' AS location),
        STRUCT('C2', '2011-01-01 11:00:00', '2011-02-02 13:00:00', 'eid2', 'title2', 'loc2')] AS experience;

CREATE TEMP TABLE B AS 
SELECT 'id1' AS id, 'C2_new' company, '2011-02-01 11:00:00' starts_at, '2011-03-02 13:00:00' ends_at, 'eid2_new' eid, 'title_new' title, 'loc2_new' location;

UPDATE A
   SET A.experience = ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT B.company, B.starts_at, B.ends_at, B.eid, B.title, B.location FROM UNNEST(A.experience))
  FROM B
 WHERE A.id = B.id;
 
SELECT * FROM A;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, A.experience column is actually an array of struct. I modified your solution and ran it but i am getting this error : Value of type STRUCT<company STRING, starts_at STRING, ends_at STRING, ...> cannot be assigned to A.profile_experience, which has type ARRAY<STRUCT<company STRING, starts_at STRING, ends_at STRING, ...>>

Comment: I see,  then what schema table **B** has ?  Is it  **STRUCT<company STRING, starts_at STRING, ends_at STRING, ...>** and you want update all the **struct**s of  A.expereince array with same struct value of B ?

Comment: As JayTiger mentioned ,If that is the case then may be `SET A.experience = [B.experience]` this will solve the error.